# In a free module, must the intersection of two free submodules be a free submodule?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, free-modules

Let $R$ be an integral domain and $M$ be a free module over $R$.

My question is this:

> Is the intersection of two free submodules of $M$ a free submodule?

P.S: We need the intersection of two free submodules is not $\{0\}$.

Comment: Take a ring $R$ and two principal ideals $(a), (b) \subseteq R$. Is their intersection always principal?

Comment: @PaulK Yes, this is what I have thought and I know it is not true. But I don't construct a specific example.

Comment: @PaulK Especially $R$ is an integral domain.

Comment: P.P.S. The zero module is a free module on zero generators....

Comment: @rschwieb Yes,  but I think zero module don't have basis because 0 is linear dependent. I think this definition is a little insufficient.

Comment: @algebra.And.analysis Why would $0$ be in the basis? I said it has *zero* generators.  $0\notin \emptyset$

Comment: @rschwieb Sorry...in the book I saw, the definition of free module is that it has a basis...I really don't know what is zero generator......I think every free submodule and its basis relate to $R$.

Comment: @algebra.And.analysis I mean that the generating set for the $R$ module $\{0\}$ is  $\emptyset$, which has zero elements. It is vacuously linearly independent.

Comment: @rschwieb I understand what you said,  thank you. But I still feel that an $\emptyset$ can generate an element zero is a little strange.

Comment: @algebra.And.analysis The relevant convention is that the sum of nothing is $0$, so the empty set is a basis for the trivial module because it spans the module (the sum of zero elements from the set is $0$) and is linearly independent (since there's no dependence relation since there are no elements).

Comment: @PaulK There has since been a conversation about the intersection of principal ideals question [at this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3652832/29335)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P$ be a projective module which is not free over a domain $R$.  (There are such domains.) We know that we may complement $P$ with another module so that $P\oplus N$ is a free module.

Consider the module $M=N\oplus P\oplus N\oplus P$ which is an (external) direct sum of two free $R$ modules, so it is free. Clearly $N\oplus P\oplus\{0\}\oplus\{0\}\cong \{0\}\oplus P\oplus N\oplus\{0\}$ are free modules. But their intersection is, you guessed it, $\{0\}\oplus P\oplus\{0\}\oplus\{0\}\cong P$, not free.

Comment: I think we can consider $M = N \bigoplus P \bigoplus N \bigoplus P$.           I don't know whether $M = N \bigoplus P \bigoplus N $ is a free module...

Comment: Because $P \bigoplus N$ is a free module, there is a basis $S_1$. $N \bigoplus N$ is also a free module which has a basis $S_2$. $\(0, 1,0\)$ can be linear expressed by $S_1$ and $\(0, -1,0\)$ can be linear expressed by $S_2$. Thus $S_1 \bigcup S_2$ is linearly dependent.

Comment: @algebra.And.analysis Yes, sorry, I was just reading your title and forgot that you later also asked for $M$ to be free. It is easily adjusted as you noticed.

Comment: @rschwieb Sorry, $P \bigoplus N$ is also a free module.

Comment: @algebra.And.analysis As for what you wrote , $S_1\cap S_2$ doesn’t even have to be a subset of $P$, and moreover it may even be empty.  From what you’re saying you sound like you expect it to be a basis of $P$ but you are nowhere near to proving that.

Comment: @algebra.And.analysis By the way, I would encourage you to append your thoughts to your original post. As it is, the post has been closed for looking like a problem statement, and may eventually be deleted. From what you've said in comments I believe you've put some work into it, so it's in your best interest to share ( in your post, not comments.)

Comment: @algebra.And.analysis I don't think it's "too simple."  Coming up with counterexamples is an art form that can be very easy or incredibly hard, depending on the question and the person asking.  Please **do** consider transferring some of the thoughts you processed in the thread here into the original post.

Comment: @algebra.And.analysis The reason this question is not too easy is that it goes beyond principal ideal domains. For principal ideal domains (like $\mathbb Z$ or $F[x]$ for a field $F$) submodules of free modules are free modules, so you could not find a counterexample there. So you do need to know more advanced things (in this case projective modules) to come up with an example.  Many people with less experience would have a hard time going beyond PIDs.

Comment: @algebra.And.analysis I like the question but I understand why people have voted to close it. It would be a shame to lose it. Fortunately it is not too late to improve it, and I hope you are able to.