# Intersection of two principal ideals in an integral domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

Could anyone give a specific example where the intersection of two principal ideals in an integral domain is not a principal ideal?

Comment: Commutative with identity right?

Comment: @rschwieb Yes, commutative, identity, no zero divisor.

Comment: The duplicate post gives an example in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 5]$

Comment: @rschwieb:  I think you meant $(2)\cap(1-\sqrt{-5})$ in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{\color{red}-5}]$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner sorry yes, I missed the minus sign while typing on a phone. What you said!

Comment: so I imagine  $(2)\cap(1-\sqrt{-5}) = (a+b\sqrt{-5},c+d\sqrt{-5})$ for some $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb Z$; can you tell me values for $a,b,c,$ and $d$?  I don't think $(2,1-\sqrt{-5})$ is the *intersection*

Comment: @algebra.And.analysis:  the "Here" link isn't working

Comment: @J.W.Tanner....alright...

Comment: @J.W.Tanner $(2) \cap (1+\sqrt{-5})$ contains $6$ and $2(1+\sqrt{-5})$. However, 6 can only be broken down into $2*3, -2*(-3), (1+\sqrt{-5})*(1-\sqrt{-5})$. $2(1+\sqrt{-5})$ can only be broken down into $2(1+\sqrt{-5})$.

Comment: Thanks, @algebra.And.analysis; so is $(2)\cap(1-\sqrt{-5})=(6,2+2\sqrt{-5})$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, it is true. $(6, 1+\sqrt{-5}) \subset (2) \bigcap (1+\sqrt{-5}) =\{(1+\sqrt{-5})(c+d\sqrt{-5})=(c-5d)+(c+d)\sqrt{-5}\mid c-5d and c+d are even numbers, c and d are integers\}$. According to the equation, $6(c_1+d_1\sqrt{-5})+2(1+\sqrt{-5})((c_2+d_2\sqrt{-5})) = (c-5d)+(c+d)\sqrt{-5}$, there must be integers $c_1, d_1, c_2, d_2$ which let the equation is satisfied for all $c, d$ that have the properties in the upfront set.